# How to Use Include More Than Once Ef Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-core-2.1

I see there is Include() and ThenInclude() but how do I handle a situation where I need to eager load multiple tables at once?

Say I have "Item Table", "Branch Table", "Company Table", "Country Table" and "State Table".

I am staring from "Item Table", but I will need Branch information, Company Name, Country the Branch belongs too and the State the Branch belongs too.

I have do far

```
dbContext.Items.Include(x => x.Branch).ThenInclude(x => x.Company)
```

but I don't have Company nor State in this and I apparently can't do

```
 dbContext.Items.Include(x => x.Branch).ThenInclude(x => x.Country).ThenInclude(x => x.State).ThenInclude(x => x.Company)
```

Comment: `ThenInclude` is used to load *nested* relationships. I believe you just need `Include`, for each of your related entities.

Comment: Sorry, I should Company, State, Country are off the Branch table. If I try to do .Include() that is based off the Item Table. I need multiple ThenIncludes off the branch table basically.

Comment: You need to call `Include` and `ThenInclude` again if you need to include multiple sub-collections